# php Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'src' (T_STRING)

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, infowindow, advanced-custom-fields

I am having some trouble figuring out how to pull in a featured image from a custom post.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'src' (T_STRING)
```

How do I properly escape this so the featured image will echo into the info window?

Here's my code:

```
     <!--Start Map-->
  <div class="col-md-6">
        <?php
        $args = array(
          'post_type'   => 'listings',
          'posts_per_page'  => -1
        );
            // query
            $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            $NUM = 0;
            ?>

          <div id="map"></div>
              <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                var locations = [<?php while( $wp_query->have_posts() ){
              $wp_query->the_post();
                $location = get_field('address'); 
            ?>

          ['<?php echo("<a href=\"".get_the_permalink()."\" >"<img src="\".get_$thumbnail_url[0]"\"</a>"); ?>', <?php echo $location['lat']; ?>, <?php echo $location['lng'];?>, <?php $NUM++ ?>],
            <?php } ?> ];

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                  zoom: 13,
                  zoomControl: true,
                  scaleControl: false,
                  panControl: false,
                  scrollwheel: false, /*disable mouseover grab*/
                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6912527,-73.9464121), /* center map location*/
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });
                var transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();
                                transitLayer.setMap(map);

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                var marker, i;

                for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                    map: map
                  });

                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                      infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                  })(marker, i));
                }
             </script>
        </div>
  </div><!--end col map -->
```

Comment: maybe similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763179/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-string

Answer (score 0):

The error come from that block of code :

```
var locations = [<?php while( $wp_query->have_posts() ){
          $wp_query->the_post();
            $location = get_field('address'); 
        ?>

      ['<?php echo("<a href=\"".get_the_permalink()."\" >"<img src="\".get_$thumbnail_url[0]"\"</a>"); ?>', <?php echo $location['lat']; ?>, <?php echo $location['lng'];?>, <?php $NUM++ ?>],
        <?php } ?> ];
```

You should use more indentations to have a clearer view of your code. Here's the fixed version (I hope) :

```
var locations = [
<?php while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php $location = get_field('address'); ?>

    [
      '<?php echo "<a href=\"".get_the_permalink()."\" ><img src=\"".get_thumbnail_url[0]."\"></a>"; ?>',
      <?php echo $location['lat']; ?>,
      <?php echo $location['lng'];?>,
      <?php $NUM++ ?>
    ],

<?php endwhile; ?> 
];
```